# JS Access Object property when this is not what we want

Tags: javascript

I know my topic title isn't clear so here is a short code to explain :

```
function SomeFunction() {
    var objPointer = this;
    this.someProp = null;
    this.someSingleton = null;
    this.someCallerToMethodWithCallback = function(){
       this.someSingletone = new someLibObj(arg1,arg2,...);
       this.someSingletone.someMethodWithCallback(arg1,arg2,...,this.someCallback);
    };
    this.someCallback = function(param1){
        this.someProp // inaccessible due to "this" is referring to someLibObj
        objPointer.someProp // accesible
    };
}
```

As you see, I defined object, which contains someSingleton - instance of someLibObj, then im calling someMethodWithCallback, where callback function is in my object, But inside this callback function "this" is not referring to my object,but to object, which called that callback.

And I'm curious :
 **Is there any simpler way to access my object, than storing "this" inside another ovariable?**

Comment: you are assigning it to a variable and accessing it later on when the original reference is lost. one assignment statement and one statement to invoke. i believe that is as simple as it can ever get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think replacing `this.someCallback` with `this.someCallback.bind(this)` in the `this.someSingletone.someMethodWithCallback...` line should do.